# Azure search usage is full. Due to this I can't upload files there. How to reduce the azure search usage

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

[image]

[image]

I tried to upload the files in language studio CustomQuestionAnswer and got 400 error and also the azure search usage is full. My expectation is azure search usage should be reduced and also the files need to be uploaded.

Comment: you try clearing the space in your cognitive search using these [RestAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/document-operations)

Answer (score 0):

The 400 error is due to some connection issue. There will be no specific limitation of the knowledge base count. There can be any number of questions and we can design patterns in the knowledge base.

The language studio has only 2 types of pricing tiers. S and F0. So, there will be no limitation for the count of the knowledge base question and answers.

[image]

If needed, we can create new language resource. Otherwise, we can use the existing language resource.

[image]

In the above example, we have nearly 18 pages visible and still more pages are available. The test is also performing well without any issue. Once check with the language resource if the same 400 problem raised.